# How can I load/render a php document in react?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I have an imports folder in my `create-react-app` under src. In there I have two index.php web pages. I've tried using `window.loction = "local:3000/path..."` and anchor tags `<a href="local:3000/path...">` but it's not allowing me to access my php files this way. When I use to use XAMPP you could easily just enter "localhost/projectname/index.php" into the url. I'm new to react and have been trying to research a solution for the past 3 days. I also can't seem to do it with `react-router-dom`. If you know why this isn't working or know how to locate non-react JS files in your project directory please help me out.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Are you running a web server that supports PHP?

Comment: No I'm using the default react-create-app server which opens your app on localhost:3000 with the command npm start

Comment: @TomFenech Do you think if maybe I created a new react project in htdocs in XAMPP this would work?

Comment: In that case, even if you put the PHP files in a publicly accessible directory within your project, this wouldn't behave in the way you expect, since the PHP in the files would not be executed. You will need to run a separate PHP server. But it is still unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm making a portfolio and and I've rendered some pictures of each project I've made. I want to be able to click on the picture and then just like how  `href="https://www.google.com"` would take you to google, I want when I click on the rendered component/picture to redirect me to my project which I made using index.php instead of index.html @TomFenech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create-react-app` runs a local server that doesn't support PHP files. What I did to make this work was create a project in htdocs and used my XAMPP server to host my PHP files. I had to install react, webpack, and babel manually which to took some research, but all in all I learned a lot and relative linking behaves the way I want it to.